# Need Explanation for C++ output

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int i = 100,sum=0;
for(int i =0; i!=10;++i)
    sum+=i;
std::cout<<i<<" "<<sum<<std::endl;
return 0 ;
}
```

I'm a beginner in C++ , the output of the code is `100 45`  . I understand 100 as its block scope but why 45?

Comment: What were you expecting `sum` to be?

Comment: What is the sum of `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + 9`?

Comment: thanks now I got it : )

Comment: You should use a debugger for these kinds of questions (or even pen and paper) and check how the variables change from one instruction to another.

Answer (score 2):

As `sum` is declared in the outer scope and not redefined inside your loop, the loop is operating on the outer `sum` which means it's value ends up equivalent to the cumulative value of the loop scoped i which would be:
`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45`

The ***i*** variable is instead redefined in the loop scope (***int i=0;***), therefore while in the loop block it goes from 0 to 9, but once out of the loop the ***i*** variable is taken into account is the one with 100 assigned.

Next time, if you have the tools, I'd recommend stepping through the loop with a debugger and having a look at what the variables and values are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You display `i` and `sum` right after it.
At the start of your loop `i=100` and as you declare another `i` in the scope of your loop, when the code goes out of the scope of your loop, it display the value of the first `i`, that is 100  and `sum = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45`.